# WebSphere 6.1 Change Class loader order

Tags: websphere-6.1

I want to change the class loader delegation order on a web module deployed to WAS6.1 from it's default of parent first to parent last.  The reason is I would like to use JSF 1.2 etc and WAS6.1 doesn't normally support it.

In the integrated solutions console for the locally deployed instance, under `Enterprise Applications > MyAppEAR  > Manage Modules > MyApp.war` the Class loader order drop down is greyed out.

1. Why is it greyed out?
2. How can I ungrey it out?
3. Would it be better to put a directive in the deployment descriptor?
4. If the answer to (3) is anything other than No, please can you specify exactly the code to do this.

I can't for the life of me find the answers to these questions on the web.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same thing. I needed to set the classloader to PARENT_LAST but the setting was greyed out. I 'solved' it by manually putting a deployment.xml file (contents below) in META-INF/ibmconfig/cells/defaultCell/applications/defaultApp/deployments/defaultApp of your ear project.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<appdeployment:Deployment xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:appdeployment="http://www.ibm.com/websphere/appserver/schemas/5.0/appdeployment.xmi" xmi:id="Deployment_1212499072929">
  <deployedObject xmi:type="appdeployment:ApplicationDeployment" xmi:id="ApplicationDeployment_1212499072929" startingWeight="10">
    <modules xmi:type="appdeployment:WebModuleDeployment" xmi:id="WebModuleDeployment_1212499072929" startingWeight="10000" uri="yourwarproject.war" classloaderMode="PARENT_LAST"/>
    <classloader xmi:id="Classloader_1212499072929" mode="PARENT_LAST"/>
  </deployedObject>
</appdeployment:Deployment>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem!
I needed to change:

- enable reload of classes: reloadEnabled="true"
- update interval: ???    (still searching, any help appreciated)

here my deployment xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<appdeployment:Deployment xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:appdeployment="http://www.ibm.com/websphere/appserver/schemas/5.0/appdeployment.xmi" xmi:id="Deployment_1310499119656">
  <deployedObject xmi:type="appdeployment:ApplicationDeployment" xmi:id="ApplicationDeployment_1310499119656" startingWeight="10" warClassLoaderPolicy="SINGLE" reloadEnabled="true">
    <modules xmi:type="appdeployment:WebModuleDeployment" xmi:id="WebModuleDeployment_1310499119656" startingWeight="10000" uri="tcm_portal_web_six.war" classloaderMode="PARENT_LAST"/>
    <modules xmi:type="appdeployment:WebModuleDeployment" xmi:id="WebModuleDeployment_1310499119657" startingWeight="10000" uri="tcm_portal_lib.war" classloaderMode="PARENT_LAST"/>
    <classloader xmi:id="Classloader_1310499119656" mode="PARENT_LAST"/>
  </deployedObject>
</appdeployment:Deployment>
```

BR
Dirk